# Recuperar json através de uma url usando ajax

Tags: ajax, json

Tenho esse metodo que busca os dados que estao em um arquivo txt e popula uma tabela:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#example').DataTable({
        "ajax": "objects.txt",
        "columns": [
            { "data": "name" },
            { "data": "position" },
            { "data": "office" },
            { "data": "extn" },
            { "data": "start_date" },
            { "data": "salary" }
        ]
    });
});
```

Como posso modificar esse método para buscar uma url, que retorna um json?

essa é a url: http://localhost:55959/Cliente/getBydesc

Comment: Buscar o que? Sua dúvida não está muito clara. Clique em [edit] e adicione mais detalhes.

Comment: Já testaste `"ajax": "http://localhost:55959/Cliente/getBydesc",` ?

Comment: Diego, essa url retorna um json

Comment: Substitua `objects.txt` com a URL que você deseja

Comment: deu certo, fiz como o Sergio e o Giacarlo sugeriram e funcionou legal, abraço